Airflow - Could not read served logs - 503 Service Unavailable
After some changes logs are not visible in Web-UI, but log-file in log-catalog in worker container is OK
Airflow 2.7.3, installed in Docker (Portainer) with containers (and with proxy), CeleryExecutor
Error

f2ad1c31c101
*** Could not read served logs: Server error '503 Service Unavailable' for url
'http://f2ad1c31c101:8793/log/dag_id=run_one_model_DAG/run_id=manual__2024-05-15T17:18:04.870528+00:00/task_id=one_model.model1_run/attempt=1.log'

worker_log_server_port = 8793 (in config, default)
Port 8793 was not in old version of docker-compose, but worked.
Where to find why 503?
Seems, all other modules in Airflow are working
Restart of Stack in Portainer not helped

"volumes" indicated in docker-compose in two blocks - first in "airflow-common" for include, second in "webserver" as is
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  volumes:
  - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
...
airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    ...
    volumes:
    ...

And second dosn't contain volume with logs...
So after adding volume with logs in webserver section - all OK, logs are visible in UI
Something strange, why error is like logs are remote and code 503...
